# Get Firebase Document of current user in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying to upload an image to the Firebase Storage and create a reference of the uploaded image link within my currently authenticated user's **Firestore Document**. Where I keep struggling is when trying to find the **Document ID** of the currently authenticated user to be able to save an image reference link.

I have added this screenshot of my Firestore Database to visualize it easier:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also if you're trying to show the profile picture (correct me if I'm wrong), this might help :)

```
    func showProfilePicture() {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                let storage = Storage.storage()
                let storageRef = storage.reference(withPath: "\(uid)/photos/\(0)")
                PhotoUploader.downloadImageUrl(from: storageRef) {[weak self] (url) in
                    guard let url = url else { return }
                    self?.displayProfileImage.downloaded(from: url, contentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
                }
    } else {
        showAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: "Not signed in")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! `let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`

Answer (score 0):

For the future I recommend you to safe the userid also in the document